# Select particular columns and insert in another table

Tags: sql-server

My tables are defined like below:

```
#TempData(ColmnA, ColumnB) -- Temp table.
EmployeeDSU(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE)
```

`#TempData` is coming from .csv file and columns may change.

Now, what I want to do is:
If `ColumnA`, `ColumnB` exists in `EmployeesDSU` table, then the `#TempData` data should be inserted into `EmployeesDSU` table, and for all the remaining columns in `EmployeesDSU` table, `NULL` should be inserted. I should do this everything in Stored procedure.

Can anybody please suggest me how to do!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. But can't you just check the `sys.columns` table for matching columns and then do the inserts as you see fit?

Comment: Why do you not know ahead of time whether EmployeeDSU contains those columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempData') is not null drop table #TempData;
select 1 ColumnA, 1 ColumnB into #TempData;

if not exists(
  select
    *
  from
    (
      select
        c.name
      from
        tempdb.sys.columns c
      where
        c.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempData')
    ) a
    left join (
      select
        *
      from
        sys.columns c
      where
        c.object_id = object_id('dbo.EmployeeDSU')
    ) b on a.name = b.name
  where
    b.name is null
) begin

  insert into dbo.EmployeeDSU(ColumnA, ColumnB)
  select
    t.ColumnA, t.ColumnB
  from
    #TempData t
  ;

end;
```